# customizeToolbar in mediawiki

Tags: php, mediawiki

In my project i need to customize the toobar section of mediawiki editor.
I read the article: [*Extension:WikiEditor/Toolbar customization* on mediawiki.org](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aWikiEditor/Toolbar_customization).

In the basic step they specified like:
"So, to customizing the toolbar, put in your User:YourUserName/common.js a code such as this:.."

I didn't get the idea regarding this...

So please help me in order to customize the toolbar

Answer (score 4):

Users can define custom javascript code in MediaWiki by editing the wiki page `User:<username>/common.js` (you need to enable [$wgAllowUserJs](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3a%24wgAllowUserJs) for it to work). For sites that you administer, you don't want to do that; instead place the script in the wiki page `MediaWiki:Common.js`, which affects every user and visitor.

Comment: Also, don't be surprised if some of the instuctions in the WikiEditor customization manual do not work.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do two steps:

1. Edit the file `mediawiki\includes\EditPage.php`. It is a good idea first to make a copy of it. The function to edit is `getEditToolbar`. Edit the `$toolarray`. You can find plenty of example code via Google, [here is one example for various common edit buttons](http://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Help_talk%3aEdit_toolbar#Wikipedia.27s_Toolbar%3a_21_Items.21).
2. Add images to `mediawiki\skins\common\images`. These are the images for the buttons. [You can find example images here](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Mediawiki_edit_toolbar).

Please remember - if you upgrade your software you will need manually to merge the `EditPage.php` file.

Comment: Don't edit core files. Don't follow advice based on a 5 year old discussion thread, MediaWiki has changed a lot since then.

Comment: The code in the "here is one example" link (which adds buttons by modifying `mwCustomEditButtons[mwCustomEditButtons.length]`) worked for me for the version of MediaWiki installed on sourceforge.net. The code suggested by other sources (e.g. http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Custom_edit_buttons) did not work for me.